# Absolute within position relative div?

Tags: html, css, position

Essentially I have two images a lamp with no light and one with a light and when the user hovers over the image it flicks the light on.

I'm trying to position the lamp to a specific location with position absolute which is fine but whenever I scale the page it changes position, now I know this is because it's out of the flow of the page so I read on related topics to put it within a div with position relative, I've done this but it still doesn't work.

```css
#cont {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
#cont a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 69px;
  left: 350px;
}
.foo img:last-child {
  display: none
}
.foo:hover img:first-child {
  display: none
}
.foo:hover img:last-child {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<section class="flexheader">
  <img class="logo" alt="" src="image/logo.png">
  <img class="house" alt="" src="image/house.png">
  <div id="cont">
    <a class="foo" href="#">
      <img alt="" src="image/lampnolight.png">
      <img alt="" src="image/lamp.png">
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Appreciate the help but it doesn't seem to be working when I scale my website it still doesn't stay where I want it, maybe if I post my full code? ill update my post.

Comment: https://github.com/AndrewMC1994/Sherlock

Comment: That's on it on github I don't know if that would be useful?

Comment: Will check.....

Comment: That looks excellent, you need to use `@media` queries for this. I couldn't find a fault in it when I tried. What's the problem here? https://rawgit.com/AndrewMC1994/Sherlock/master/index.html

Comment: Well basically I want lamp to be like this:https://s30.postimg.org/5rj3yprwx/Untitled_1.jpg

Comment: but whenever you shrink the page the lamp move from it's original position?

Comment: Boss, you need to do a lot for that. For these kind of position relative UIs, you should really use a fixed width container than having a fluid one.

Comment: Ah ok, I appreciate the help would you know of any guides on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this to make the scaling work perfectly:

```css
.flexheader,
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
.flexheader,
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cont {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
#cont a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 69px;
  left: 350px;
}
.foo img:last-child {
  display: none;
}
.foo:hover img:first-child {
  display: none;
}
.foo:hover img:last-child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section class="flexheader">
  <img class="logo" alt="" src="//placehold.it/100?text=logo" />
  <img class="house" alt="" src="//placehold.it/100?text=house" />
  <div id="cont">
    <a class="foo" href="#">
      <img alt="" src="//placehold.it/100?text=lampnolight" />
      <img alt="" src="//placehold.it/100/ccf?text=lamp" />
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```